# Keep output in box in bash script

Tags: bash, output, border

I am working on a bash script, and making it look nice. I want all outputted commands in a box. This box automatically sized when launched.
I made a drawBox function
Code:

```
drawBox ()
{
if [ "$1" ] && [ "$2" ] && [ "$3" ] && [ "$4" ]; then
    printilly=$4
    printillx=$3
    tput cup $1 $2
    num=0
    while [ "$num" -lt "$4" ]; do
        printf "$boxcar" ## The boxcar is the character used for
        num=`expr $num + 1` ##printing the box
    done
    num=1
    sth=`expr $1 + 1 - 1`
    while [ "$num" -lt "$3" ]; do
        tput cup $sth $2
        printf "$boxcar"
        num=`expr $num + 1`
        sth=`expr $sth + 1`
    done
    num=1
    sth=`expr $1 + 1 - 1`
    wid=`expr $4 + $2 - 1`
    while [ "$num" -lt "$3" ]; do
        tput cup $sth $wid
        printf "$boxcar"
        num=`expr $num + 1`
        sth=`expr $sth + 1`
    done
    num=0
    hei=`expr $1 + $3 - 1`
    tput cup $hei $2
    while [ "$num" -lt "$4" ]; do
        printf "$boxcar"
        num=`expr $num + 1`
    done

else
    if [ "$1" == "-help" ]; then
        echo "-help displays this screen"
        echo 'Usage: "drawBox start-height start-width height width"'
        echo "Made by NAME REDACTED May, 20, 2015"
    else
        echo 'Cannot draw box! Storing error info to log.txt'
        echo "[`date`]Invalid Syntax! Please use drawBox start-height start-width height width" > log.txt
    fi
fi
}
```

That is the code for drawing the box. I just need to figure out how to actually make the output staying in the box, without printing over the box characters. basically I need to keep the code inside the border. Like this

```
█████████████████████████████████
█Title Here                     █
█████████████████████████████████
█Code output here               █
█without covering the box       █
█but staying inside the box     █
█████████████████████████████████
```

Is this possible without using tput cup $y $x after every command? I dont like that method because sometimes a command can take up more than one line, making tput cup infective, by printing over the box. Is this possible? Also, the functions syntax is
$ drawBox start-height start-width height width
start height being at what height does the box start
start width being what width the box starts
height how tall the box is.
width how long the box is.
(edit: Please set boxcar using "boxcar=[character]" to define a character to use. Box may not work properly if not define, or may be printed as "0" Fill in [character] without square brackets, to what you want the box character to be)

Answer (score 0):

It would be easy if your terminal had the capabilities

```
       set_bottom_margin_parm        smgbp
       set_left_margin_parm          smglp
       set_right_margin_parm         smgrp
       set_top_margin_parm           smgtp
```

or

```
       set_lr_margin                 smglr
       set_tb_margin                 smgtb
```

or

```
       set_window                    wind
```

(see [**Defined Capabilities**](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xcurses/terminfo.html#tag_002_001_003)). Unfortunately, many terminals haven't. If that's the case with yours, you could look into [dialog(1): dialog boxes from shell scripts](http://linux.die.net/man/1/dialog) - perhaps this would meet your needs.